# How to change other items in a Android ListView when one item is clicked

Tags: android, android-listview, listviewitem

I have a `ListView` that contains items with checkboxes that should behave sometimes like a `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` and sometimes like a `CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE`. What I mean is for certain items in the list, when selected certain other items needs to be deselected whilst other can remain selected.

So when item **A** is checked I can find in my data the item **B** that needs to be unchecked but how do I get the UI to refresh to show this as I (I believe) cannot find the actual `View` that represents **B** but just it's data?

Comment: I figured it out, I can use `getChildAt` and `getFirstVisiblePosition` to find the actual `View` I need to update by taking the items index and subtracting the value returned by `getFirstVisiblePosition`.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're off to a good start.  You're right that you should be manipulating the underlying data source for item B when A is clicked.

Two tips that may help you:

1. Your `getView()` method in the Adapter should be looking at your data source and changing `convertView` based on what it finds.  You cannot find the actual View that represents B because in a `ListView`, the `Views` are recycled and get reused as different data needs to be displayed.  Basically, when an item is scrolled off the list, the `View` that was used gets passed to the `getView()` function as `convertView`, ready to handle the next element's data.  For this reason, you should probably never directly change a `View` in a `ListView` based on user input, but rather the underlying data.
2. You can call `notifyDataSetChanged()` from within your adapter to signal that somewhere the underlying data has been changed and `getView()` should be called again for the elements currently displayed in your list.

If you're still having trouble, feel free to post some code that illustrates the specific problem that you're having.  It's much easier to provide concrete advice when the problem is better defined.  Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can use singleChoice alartDialog, i have used like:

```
private int i = 0; // this is global
private final CharSequence[] items = {"Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"}; // this is global

Button settings = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.settings);

settings.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(v.getContext());

    //Title of Popup
    builder.setTitle("Settings");

    builder.setSingleChoiceItems(items, i,
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
       // When you click the radio button
       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item){

           i=item;
       }
    });

    builder.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
           new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

          if (i == 0) {
                  //it means 1st item is checked, so do your code
          }
          if (i == 1) {
             //it means 2nd item is checked, so do your code
          } /// for more item do if statement    
        }
    });
      //When you click Cancel, Leaves PopUp.
      builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null); 
      builder.create().show();

    }
});
```

i have initialized `i=0`, so that for the very first time when user click on `settings` button, the first item is selected. and after then when user select other item, i have saved the `i` value so that next time when user click `settings` button, i can show user his/her previously selected item is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I come across and solve this question today.

```
public class ItemChooceActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

       private int chosenOne = -1;

      class Madapter extends BaseAdapter {
                 .....
                 .....
       @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            if (chosenOne != position) {
                set the view in A style
            } else {
                set the view in B style
            }

        return convertView;
    }
}



        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int position,
        long arg3) {
    ,,,,
        chosenOne = position;
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
         ,,,
}
```

}